# Create Json Message using JsonCpp

Tags: c++, json, jsoncpp

I'm trying to create a Json message using Jsoncpp.
I've done as follows:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>    
#include <json/json.h>

int main()
{
  std::string Value = "5.17e9";
  std::string Type = "TX";
  std::string Parameter = "Frequency";

  Json::Value root; 
  root.append("Type");
  root.append("Parameter");
  root.append("Value");
  root["Type"] = Type;
  root["Parameter"] = Parameter;
  root["Value"] = Value; 

  Json::FastWriter fastwriter;
  std::string message = fastwriter.write(root);
  std::cout<<message<<std::endl;

  return 0;
 }
```

compiling this code using the following command line:

```
g++ -o clients clients.cpp -ljsoncpp -lzmq
```

This Kind of error occurs:

```
clients.cpp:(.text._ZN20multi_usrp_emulation7client1Ev[_ZN20multi_usrp_emulation7client1Ev    ]+0x1d9): undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator=(Json::Value)'
clients.cpp:(.text._ZN20multi_usrp_emulation7client1Ev[_ZN20multi_usrp_emulation7client1Ev    ]+0x224): undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator=(Json::Value)'
clients.cpp:(.text._ZN20multi_usrp_emulation7client1Ev[_ZN20multi_usrp_emulation7client1Ev    ]+0x26c): undefined reference to `Json::Value::operator=(Json::Value)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

What is wrong with my code?

Comment: What version of jsoncpp are you using? Perhaps it is related to this issue: https://github.com/open-source-parsers/jsoncpp/issues/484 ?

Comment: I don't how to check the version. But I've downloaded today via github. I read the question that you attached but I didn't understand it well..can you help me?

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure about the link error, but there is a problem with the code that might be handled differently in your compiler. It's a runtime error for me.

```
Json::Value root; 
root.append("Type"); // makes root into arrayValue
root["Type"] = Type; // accesses root as an objectValue
// triggers assert in Json::Value::resolveReference
```

this is how I do it:

```
Json::Value root; 
root["Type"] = Type;
```